# How to show Article Views in Blogspot?

Tags: blogs, blogger, blogspot

I want to show the article views for each of my `blogspot` article. For now, I can show only `Total PageViews` in my blog which is the count of views of all my pages but now I want to show view of each article. Is it possible in `blogspot`?

Answer (score 1):

By default, blogger doesn't have the option to display post views to public. It will only show the total blog view count. But, you can still see it in your blogger dashboard.

External widgets are available to serve your needs. You have to add external scripts to your page to show individual post views. Add any one of the external widgets available,which is suitable to your requirements.